# How to get certificate for "www.*.example.org" with Traefik's dnsChallange?

Tags: django, deployment, traefik, lets-encrypt, acme

With the config below the issued certificate works for `www.example.org` and `abc.example.org`.but doesn't work for `www.abc.example.org`.

```
http:
  routers:
    web-router:
      rule: "Host(`example.org`) ||
       Host(`www.example.org`) ||
       HostRegexp(`{subdomain:[a-z-]+}.example.org`) ||
       HostRegexp(`www.{subdomain:[a-z-]+}.example.org`)"

      entryPoints:
        - web
      middlewares:
        - redirect
        - csrf
      service: django


    web-secure-router:
      rule: "Host(`example.org`) ||
       Host(`www.example.org`) ||
       HostRegexp(`{subdomain:[a-z-]+}.example.org`) ||
       HostRegexp(`www.{subdomain:[a-z-]+}.example.org`)"

      entryPoints:
        - web-secure
      middlewares:
        - csrf
      service: django
      tls:
        certResolver: letsencrypt
        domains:
          - main: "*.example.org"
            sans:
              - "example.org"

certificatesResolvers:
  letsencrypt:
    acme:
      email: "email@example.com"
      storage: /etc/traefik/acme/acme.json
      dnsChallenge:
        provider: route53
        delayBeforeCheck: 0
```

In the DNS I have `A` records for `example.org` and `*.example.org`.

Is it possible to get a certificate that works for `www.*.example.org` and `*.example.org` in the same time?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

LetsEncrypt doesn't do nested wildcards. You can get a certificate for `*.example.org` or for `*.sub.example.org`, but `*.example.org` doesn't include `.` in the definition of `*`.

Furthermore, DNS itself doesn't support nested or embedded wildcards.

You can see this if you create a record for `www.*.example.com` and then query for something like `www.foo.example.com`. You'll get an NXDOMAIN response. If you query for `www.\*.example.com` (or wrap the FQDN in single quotes to avoid shell expansion), then you'll get the A record you created. The asterisk becomes a literal character when not at the beginning of the record.

```
➤ host www.sub.productionwebsite.com 8.8.8.8
Using domain server:
Name: 8.8.8.8
Address: 8.8.8.8#53
Aliases:

Host www.sub.productionwebsite.com not found: 3(NXDOMAIN)
~
➤ host 'www.*.productionwebsite.com' 8.8.8.8
Using domain server:
Name: 8.8.8.8
Address: 8.8.8.8#53
Aliases:

www.*.productionwebsite.com has address 10.68.0.73
```